# Relation between change of basis and projection onto a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have two orthogonal vectors $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$  that span $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to find the coordinates of $x$ in the basis spanned by $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$. Normally, I would set up the following system.

$x = c_1\Psi_1 + c_2\Psi_2$

$x_1 = c_1 \Psi_1(1) + c_2 \Psi_2(1)$

$x_2 = c_1 \Psi_1(2) + c_2 \Psi_2(2)$

to solve for the new coordinates $c_1$ and $c_2$. However, in my signal processing class, I also saw the following claim.

$c_1 = \frac{\langle x, \Psi_1 \rangle}{\langle \Psi_1, \Psi_1 \rangle}$

$c_2 = \frac{\langle x, \Psi_2 \rangle}{\langle \Psi_2, \Psi_2 \rangle}$

Geometrically, this kind of makes sense. But I was wondering what theorem / algebraic proof binds the two methods together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\begin{bmatrix}\Psi_1(1)&\Psi_2(1)\\\Psi_1(2)&\Psi_2(2)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} \quad \Psi\vec c=\vec x \iff \vec c=\Psi^{-1}\vec x$$

and

$$\Psi^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\Psi_1(1)}{\langle \Psi_1, \Psi_1 \rangle}&\frac{\Psi_1(2)}{\langle \Psi_1, \Psi_1 \rangle}\\\frac{\Psi_2(1)}{\langle \Psi_2, \Psi_2 \rangle}&\frac{\Psi_2(2)}{\langle \Psi_2, \Psi_2 \rangle}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Note that $\Psi^{-1}$ is obtained by $\Psi^T$ and dividing the entries by the  $\langle \Psi_1, \Psi_1 \rangle$ terms to take into account that the basis is orthogonal and not orthonormal.

Comment: Just to confirm - the original claim would not hold if the basis vectors were just linearly independent and not orthogonal right?

Comment: @Carpetfizz Yes that's the main advantage to use orthonormal system since for $\vec v=\sum c_i \vec x_i$ we have $c_i=\vec v\cdot \vec x_i$.